# Register instance for interception in Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, interception, unity-interception

For my Unit Tests I am currently mocking my interceptor and intercepted classes using Moq, then registering the intercepted instance in Unity and setting the default interceptor for the interface. I then resolve the instance and call methods on the intercepted and verify that the interception method is being called.

```
_mockInterceptor = new Mock<ExternalInterceptor>().As<IInterceptRelay>();
_mockInterception = new Mock<TestInterception> { CallBase = true }.As<IInterceptRelay>();

Container.RegisterInstance(_mockInterception.Object as ITestInterception);
UnityContainer.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<ITestInterception>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

var test = Container.Resolve<ITestInterception>();
var returnValue = test.TestTheExternalInterception(TestMessage);

_mockInterceptor.Verify(i => i.ExecuteAfter(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<IEnumerable>(), It.IsAny<LoggingInterceptionAttribute>(), It.IsAny<IMethodResult>()), Times.Once());
```

This works great, however I would rather set the interception during registration like I do when I register a service/singleton to keep everything consistent.

```
// Typical registration
UnityContainer.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>());
// Singleton registration
UnityContainer.RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(), new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>());
```

I cannot see any way to configure interception using the `IUnityContainer.RegisterInstance()` method as it doesn't take any `InjectionMembers`. I can actually use interception with an instance if I call `UnityContainer.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<T>()` before resolving.

Is there a better/easier way of registering or mocking an interceptor?

Comment: What are you attempting to test here?  You don't need any mocks because your unit tests shouldn't need to test that Unity can perform interception.  I would even argue that you shouldn't use Unity in your unit tests (just new up the class you are testing).  It would be just as effective to use reflection to determine if the LoggingInterception attribute is present on the member under test.

Comment: @TylerOhlsen In typical cases this is true, however I am using an abstracted IoC framework that allows any IoC container to be dropped in in place of Unity. In these cases I am running the same tests against all of my chosen IoC frameworks that support interception, and testing that the abstraction is working as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity Interception offers to create proxies without resolving them by unity. You can then `RegisterInstance` the object you've created yourself.

For more infromation see [Dependency Injection with Unity](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/D/B/4DBC771D-9E24-4211-ADC5-65812115E52D/DependencyInjectionWithUnity.pdf) page 77 "Interception Without the Unity Container".

I took the following example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx#sec13):

```
ITenantStore tenantStore = Intercept.ThroughProxy<ITenantStore>(
    new TenantStore(tenantContainer, blobContainer),
    new InterfaceInterceptor(),
    new IInterceptionBehavior[]
    {
        new LoggingInterceptionBehavior(),
        new CachingInterceptionBehavior()
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this will do just nicely.

Comment: What if the object is already created by the time you get here?

Comment: @claudekennilol which object? The `TenantStore`? Just replace `new TenantStore(tenantContainer, blobContainer)` with a reference to the existing object...